# uitableview headerViewForSection: always returns nil

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a table with custom header views that no matter when, or what value I choose for section, I always get nil value. I have another table with the same problem.

I can see the header views if I print the value of [tableview subviews], but I don't know why the method won't return anything.

What I am trying to do is to get an activityIndicator that is in the headerview and start it or stop it with a method call.

The headers are always painted ok, but I can't get a reference back to it. Also, calling `headerViewForSection:` doesn't call the delegate method, is that normal?

`footerViewForSection:` has the same problem

Some code:

```
- (UIView*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSArray* objs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"iPadTableCells" owner:nil options:nil];
    UIView* header = [objs objectAtIndex: 0];

    UIActivityIndicatorView* activityIndicator = (UIActivityIndicatorView*) [header viewWithTag:5];
    [activityIndicator startAnimating]

    return header;

}
```

from any method:

```
    UIView* headerView = [tableview headerViewForSection: section];  //returns nil

    if (headerView) {
        UIActivityIndicatorView* activityIndicator = (UIActivityIndicatorView*)[headerView viewWithTag: 5];
        [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    }
```

Comment: Some code would be useful...

Comment: @Scott it's pretty straightforward, but I add some code, thanks

Comment: Is the second code block called when the tableView is visible?

Comment: and have you implemented tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:?

Comment: @Rakesh yes, i tested to call that from a button click action, trying to retrieve a header for all table sections

Comment: okey.. and the `tableView:height...`?

Comment: In your test, did you check to see that tableview was not nil?

Comment: @htafoya,                                                        Make sure, 
1.UITableView delegate and datasource get connected.
2.numberOfSectionsInTableView greater than '0'. 
3.heightForHeaderInSection returns your custom header-view height.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Answer

From the docs:

> To make the table view aware of your header or footer view, you need to register it. You do this using the `registerNib:forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:` or `registerClass:forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:` method of `UITableView`.

(The Swift equivalent is  `register(_:forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:)`.)

So you need to register the nib, and then get it using a reuse identifier, instead of pulling it straight out of the app bundle, which is what you're doing now.

...if you want to use the `headerViewForSection` method.

## Alternate Answer

Alternatively, you could check whether to keep spinning inside the `viewForHeaderInSection` method and then send just call:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

To refresh the section header.

(Note that this alternative approach will destroy and recreate your whole view, so if you have a big table with lots of data, it may not be very efficient.)

Comment: Thanks, this what I was looking for, However I noticed that this method is from IOS 6 and above, and I need something from 4.2. Then I realized that **headerViewForSection** is also from 6.0. I guess i will then just refresh the whole section I want. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 9):

*It's been awhile since this question was asked and recently I had come across a similar issue and had asked my own question here:* [UITableView -headerViewForSection returns (null)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20188049/uitableview-headerviewforsection-returns-null)
*I believe I have the answer.*

---

### Prerequisite Steps:

1. Create a `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` subclass and name it `CustomHeaderView`
2. Create a view interface nib file for the class (*apparently you have named it `iPadTableCells` here*)
3. In the xib, select the View & in it's **Identity Inspector**

   - Specify the **Custom Class** as `CustomHeaderView`
4. Make a property, synthesize and connect it to the xib

   - `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;`

---

Use the following code:

```
- (UIView*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    static NSString *HeaderIdentifier = @"header";
    CustomHeaderView *header = [tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:HeaderIdentifier];

    if(!header) {
        NSArray* objs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"iPadTableCells"
                                                      owner:nil
                                                    options:nil];
        header = [objs objectAtIndex: 0];
    }

    [header.activityIndicator startAnimating];
    return header;
}
```

then you can access it this way:

```
CustomHeaderView *headerView = (CustomHeaderView*)[tableView headerViewForSection:section];
[headerView.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
```

Comment: I believe you are writing the same that I already posted (custom view, method calling). That didn't work as header must be registered first, and that method and also headerViewForSection method is only iOS6.0 and above.

Comment: @htafoya : actually it was all about subclassing `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`. Because i had tried with a simple `UIView` but i was still getting nil. anyways, i'll check this again later

Comment: @htafoya : i tried with `UIView` but got nil again. I made `CustomHeaderView` a subclass of `UIView` when I got nil. I changed the subclass to `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` and got the object. btw... what do you mean by "header must be registered first"? do you mean something like `[tableView registerClass:[CustomHeaderView class] forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:HeaderIdentifier];` or `[tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomHeaderView" bundle:nil] forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:HeaderIdentifier];` ??

Comment: @staticVoidMan: +1 for your comment on subclassing `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`, it pointed me into the direction that `-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section` should return a `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` to get access to it on `footerViewForSection` (and vice versa for header views...)

Comment: @TobiasHeinicke : thanks but note `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` is iOS6+. Btw... There is a way to continue using a simple `UIView`. see: ["METHOD 2:" sub-part in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20210689/2857130)

Answer (score 5):

## In swift

All you need is to create an instance of `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` for the header view you need to return

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let sectionHeaderView = UITableViewHeaderFooterView()
        //customize your view here
        return sectionHeaderView
    }
```

Comment: that's a very good answer, but if you want to customize you should do something like that 
        headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(named: "onSecondary")
        let tableViewHeader = UITableViewHeaderFooterView()
        tableViewHeader.backgroundView = headerView
        tableViewHeader.tag = section