# UITableView -headerViewForSection returns (null)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with 2 sections. Each with it's own `headerView`.
I have created a custom `headerView` via the `-viewForHeaderInSection:` method.
Later, I plan to modify it a bit so I need to use the `viewForHeader` method but I am unable to access the `headerView` and it's `subViews`.

As a simple example, I'm trying to `NSLog` the `viewForHeader` object in the `-didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` but I get a `(null)` result.

Sample Code:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 75;
}

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{    
    UIView *myHeader = [[UIView alloc] init];
    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            [myHeader setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
            break;
        case 1:
            [myHeader setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    [myLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 100, 30)];
    [myLabel setTag:101];
    [myLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [myLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Section: %d",section]];

    [myHeader addSubview:myLabel];    
    return myHeader;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *testView = [self.tableView headerViewForSection:indexPath.section];
    NSLog(@"%@",testView);  //displays (null)
}
```

---

Do I need to create the custom `UIView` xib as the `headerView`? (*because as per a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231726/uitableview-headerviewforsection-always-returns-nil) and as per the docs*")

> To make the table view aware of your header or footer view, you need to register it.
>   You do this using the registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier: or
>   registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier: method of UITableView.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## METHOD 1:

Ok, after some trial and error, I finally solved my own dilemma.
I did the `headerView` just as I would do a cell.

For a cell we would take `UITableViewCell` and use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`
while...
For a Header/Footer, we will take `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` and use the `dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier` method.

The rest is pretty much the same concept as a cell.

### Prerequisites:

1. Set header height to 40
2. Set number of sections to 2 or more
3. Set number of rows per section to be atleast 1
4. iOS6+ (*`UITableViewHeaderFooterView` won't work with iOS5 and below*)

---

### First Approach:

**Creating and using the default `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` within `-viewForHeaderInSection:` method:**

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    static NSString *HeaderIdentifier = @"header";

    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *myHeader = [tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:HeaderIdentifier];
    if(!myHeader) {
        myHeader = [[UITableViewHeaderFooterView alloc] initWithReuseIdentifier:HeaderIdentifier];
    }

    UIButton *btnUp = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [btnUp setTag:101];
    [btnUp setTitle:@"-" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnUp setFrame:CGRectMake(tableView.frame.size.width - 35, 5, 30, 30)];
    [myHeader addSubview:btnUp];

    [myHeader.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Section: %d",section]];

    [myHeader setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 50)];
    return myHeader;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *theHeaderView = [tableView headerViewForSection:indexPath.section];
    NSLog(@"%@",theHeaderView); // -- great! ... not (null) anymore

    UIButton *theButton = (UIButton *)[theHeaderView viewWithTag:101];
    [theButton setTitle:@"+" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

---

### Second Approach:

**Using a custom `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` subclass:**

1. Created a `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` subclass and named it `CustomHeaderView`
2. Created a View interface nib file for the class
3. In the xib, selected the View & in it's **Identity Inspector**

   - Specified the **Custom Class** as `CustomHeaderView`
4. Made properties, synthesized and connected them in the xib

   - `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblSomething;`
   - `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnSomething;`

Modified the `-viewForHeaderInSection:` & `-didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` as:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    static NSString *HeaderIdentifier = @"header";

    CustomHeaderView *myHeader = [tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:HeaderIdentifier];
    if(!myHeader) {
    //    [tableView registerClass:[CustomHeaderView class] forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:HeaderIdentifier];
        myHeader = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomHeaderView"
                                                  owner:self
                                                options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    [myHeader.btnSomething setTitle:@"-" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [myHeader.lblSomething setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Section: %d",section]];

    return myHeader;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomHeaderView *theHeaderView = (CustomHeaderView*)[tableView headerViewForSection:indexPath.section];
    NSLog(@"%@",theHeaderView);

    [theHeaderView.lblSomething setAlpha:theHeaderView.lblSomething.alpha-0.1];
    [theHeaderView.btnSomething setTitle:@"+" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

---

*PS: The issue with `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` is that it is iOS6+ only and if, for any reason, your header is/must be a `UIView`, then see the next method*

---

## METHOD 2:

**Using a simple `UIView`:**

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *vwHeader = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [vwHeader setTag:200 + section]; //[1] first method

    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            [vwHeader setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
            break;
        case 1:
            [vwHeader setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    UILabel *lblTitle = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    [lblTitle setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 100, 30)];
    [lblTitle setTag:100 + section]; //[2] alternative method
    [lblTitle setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [lblTitle setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Section: %d",section]];

    [vwHeader addSubview:lblTitle];
    return vwHeader;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIView *vwTest = [self.tableView viewWithTag:200 + indexPath.section]; //[1]
    NSLog(@"[1] : %@",vwTest);

    //or

    UILabel *lblTest = (UILabel *)[self.tableView viewWithTag:100 + indexPath.section]; //[2]
    NSLog(@"%@",lblTest.text);
    UIView *vwTestForSuperview = lblTest.superview;
    NSLog(@"[2] : %@",vwTestForSuperview);
}
```

---

***PS:** I know this code doesn't serve any great purpose but this is just an example for others.*

Comment: great reply..second approach worked well for me.. :)

Comment: @staticVoidMan In the first approach it is also very important to remove the subviews as the header is dequeued, otherwise the subviews will be added over the already added subviews. In your case btnUp should be removed first if exists and then added to subview back

Comment: Ughhh finally! I love the second approach. Works perfect here. Thx!

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem can be solved easily enough:

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{    
UITableViewHeaderFooterView *myHeader = [[UITableViewHeaderFooterView alloc] init];
switch (section) {
    case 0:
        [myHeader setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
        break;
    case 1:
        [myHeader setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
[myLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 100, 30)];
[myLabel setTag:101];
[myLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[myLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Section: %d",section]];

[myHeader addSubview:myLabel];    
return myHeader;
```

}

Basically, you need to use *UITableViewHeaderFooterView* class to return from *viewForHeaderInSection* callback. After that, calling *headerViewForSection* on your table view will be returning you valid instances of objects instead of nil.

Comment: yes, i figured that out recently. i infact posted it as an answer here as well. I even had to dump `-setBackgroundColor` because `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` doesn't support it. Also, `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` provides a default `textLabel` so i dumped the `UILabel` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set frame.

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{    
    UIView *myHeader = [[UIView alloc] init];
    myHeader.frame   = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 75); //ADD THIS AND SET YOUR FRAME
    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            [myHeader setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
            break;
        case 1:
            [myHeader setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    [myLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 100, 30)];
    [myLabel setTag:101];
    [myLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [myLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Section: %d",section]];

    [myHeader addSubview:myLabel];    
    return myHeader;
}
```

Comment: actually, as per my observation, the frame of the `UIView` object that is returned, does not matter. If you observe the final result of `myHeader.frame.size.width`, it will not be 100. It will be equal to `tableView.frame.size.width`. try `[myHeader setFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,10,10)`; won't make a difference since the view is returned as the main `headerView` and not as a subView of some pre-existing `headerView`. anyways, setting the frame for `myHeader` still won't solve the issue.