# Accessing UITableView Header View

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView where the section header view contains a UITextField that the user can key in values. When I want to save the value that user keyed in, I need to access the table section header.

I tried using the method `headerView(forSection:)`, and I put `headerView(forSection: 0)!` as a test to make sure that the section header definitely exists, but every time when I run the programme, the line where the method is returns an error "unexpectedly found `nil` while unwrapping an optional value".

I have also tried to tag the UITextField, but when I attempt to access the section header using `certainTableView.viewWithTag(_ tag:)`, and cast the resulting UIView to UITextField, there is an error thrown at the line where casting happens, saying "Could not cast value of type 'UITableView' to 'UITextField'."

Both errors look pretty bizarre to me. In the first case, I made sure that the section header is existent, yet the method returned `nil`. In the second case, the returned tagged view should be of type UITableViewHeaderFooterView, yet the type is UITableView. Can someone suggest any possible reason why this is so and how to correct?

Or alternatively, is there any better approach to access the section header view so that I can save the text keyed in in the UITextField?

Below is the detail that I used in the first case.

In `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?`, I returned a UIView that contains a UITextField. In the table view which I need to save the keyed-in user data, I have a button that, when the user taps it, data are saved. Within that selector, I have the following:

```
//save item
    let a = addItemTableView.headerView(forSection: 0)!
    let b = a.subviews[0] as! UITextField
    let c = b.text ?? ""
    someNSManagedObject.text = c
```

The error I mentioned above appears at the first line.

Comment: please post tried code

Comment: @qsmy You need a way to save textField.text into your model, check my answer for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the post in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20188049/uitableview-headerviewforsection-returns-null), I got a hint and found out that, in `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?` method, I should return a **UITableViewHeaderFooterView** instead of the previously **UIView**. As I changed the returned object's type to UITableViewHeaderFooterView, with everything else remaining the same, (i.e. add a UITextField to the UITableViewHeaderFooterView) I managed to access the UITextField in the UITableViewHeaderFooterView via `headerView(forSection:)` method.

To Be even clearer, given in the apple's documentation that the function declaration is `func headerView(forSection section: Int) -> UITableViewHeaderFooterView?`, showing that the returned value is UITableViewHeaderFooterView, in order to access the header view using the method, the returned value from `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?` should be UITableViewHeaderFooterView instead of any other generic UIView or UIView subclasses.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

First add a property to your model `textFieldData` to save textField data in.

Then in your `HeaderViewClass` add a closure var `textFieldDidChange: ((String) -> Void)?`

```
class HeaderViewClass: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
// MARK:- IBOutlets
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

// MARK:- Variable
var textFieldDidChange: ((String) -> Void)?

// MARK:- Functions
func fill(with model: Model) {
    textField.delegate = self
    textField.text = model.textFieldData
}
}

extension HeaderViewClass: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {    
        textFieldDidChange?(textField.text)
    }
}
```

In your viewController class

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let footerView = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: PlaceOrderFooterView.id) as! PlaceOrderFooterView
    footerView.fill(with: models[section])

    footerView.textFieldDidChange = { [unowned self] text in
        self.models[section].textFieldData = text
    }

    return footerView
}
```

Now your model object has the updated value whenever any textField data is changed.

Comment: I see that your approach is to update it whenever the user edits in the text field. However, is there a way to save everything after the user finishes editing and taps the button, as I mentioned in the updated question?

Comment: If you don't save the textField.text on your model, it might be lost due to cell reusing, so you need to keep track of it.
And I think it is bad practice to try to get data from tableUI directly instead of using their model.

Comment: I am not reusing cell as I know that there can be different input for different section header. Also, I think that you are saying about MVVM, the view model layer, but I am currently using MVC. And I want to focus on solving the issue of data saving first, then start to add more abstraction layer to my code.

Answer (score 0):

In your method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {}
```

when you return your custom header containing `UITextField` , assign it's delegate to your controller, this way you'll get all keyed values by user under `UITextFieldDelegate` function