# Adding a gesture dynamically to an existing table view section header

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to add a single tap gesture to my table view section headers, using the below code. But it doesn't embed the gesture in the returned view. What am i doing wrong here? really appreciate your help.

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    UIView *view = [tableView headerViewForSection:section];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyBoard)];
    [view addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];


    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try setting a delegate to the gesture recognizer so that it is recognized together with the scroll view's (table view) gestures:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```

set the delegate like this:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyBoard)];
singleTap.delegate = self;
[view addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

You also need to make sure that the gesture only gets set once since tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section is called every time the header appears/re-appears on screen. The way you have it, you'll end up with multiple gesture recognizers to the header view.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Edwin, but I'm afraid that it didn't solve the issue. But if I try creating the view as shown below and assign the gesture it works fine. UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init]; only thing is it doesn't work when I try to assign my existing header section.

Comment: in that case I think your issue is that [tableView headerViewForSection:section] returns nil. You first need to register a class or nib to handle is. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231726/uitableview-headerviewforsection-always-returns-nil

Comment: god.. thanks a lot Edwin. That's the exact issue. It returns null. I need to register a nib. Thanks again.