# Get custom Header view of cell on click in tableview

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

In table view we have multiple section. On click of button how to get the header section title from selected tableview cell

we have tried with this code

```
UITableViewHeaderFooterView* header = [self.tableView headerViewForSection:indexPath.section];
```

but it return nil.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231726/uitableview-headerviewforsection-always-returns-nil

Comment: @joan thank you for reply but it return nil. we have already gone through that link.

Comment: can you please post the code of viewForHeaderInSection delegate?